# Resolve MITMproxy error for add on: in script mitmproxy_logging_script.py: No module named 'logging.handlers'

Tags: python, python-3.x, mitmproxy

I am using this script for mitmproxy to log mitmproxy traffic: https://github.com/kubistika/mitmproxy-logging-script

Upon launching mitmproxy, I get this error:

```
mitmdump -q -s mitmproxy_logging_script.py 
[05:36:34.003] in script mitmproxy_logging_script.py: No module named 'logging.handlers'
```

Mitmproxy version:

```
mitmproxy --version
Mitmproxy: 9.0.1 binary
Python:    3.11.0
OpenSSL:   OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022
Platform:  Linux-5.10.0-20-amd64-x86_64-with-glibc2.31
```

As I understand it, mitmproxy uses its own virtual env, but the logging module should be installed by default.

The logging module is installed already via pip3, but that shouldn't affect the virtual environment.

Comment: The script you are trying to use has not been updated for more than three years. Most likely this is the reason you get errors. It simply does not fit to the used mitmproxy version. Try an 3 years old mitmproxy version. May be then it works.

Comment: No actually the script worked fine. It was the virtual env. After installing the pypi version, the error went away.

Answer (score -2):

The answer comes from the dev here: https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/5844.

> It looks like this script is using some modules that don't ship with our precompiled binaries. In this case you want to install mitmproxy from PyPI.

Resolving the issue was as simple as installing the [PyPI version](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/overview-installation/#installation-from-the-python-package-index-pypi) of the application.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).